# ArcCatelog 9.3 feature classes with annotation relationships allowed in a geometric network

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, arccatalog, geometric-network, relationship-class

I have a gas utility dataset that we are working on getting converted into a geometric network for easier analysis.  The feature classes are part of an ArcSDE and have a ton of relationship classes attached, mostly annotations. I know that geometric networks will not accept feature to feature relationship classes when building the network, but what about relationship classes built from annotations? If we cannot get those annotation classes into the geometric network, then we might end up scrapping the idea all together in our department.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an annotation feature class as *part* of a geometric network, as it doesn't contain network data.

However, you can add feature linked annotation into the network feature dataset after creation. You may be able to import the existing annotation fc in once the network has been created.